# What would the Autofac equivalent to this Ninject code be?

Tags: c#, signalr, ninject, autofac

On the following page: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/extensibility/dependency-injection

Near the bottom (just below the text "RegisterHubs.Start") there is a piece of Ninject code that I am trying to reproduce using Autofac.

So far I have succeeded in giving myself a headache, but not much else.  I have scoured the Autofac wiki, and the web for some help.  Though, I am sure I probably missed some tidbit of information.

**Update**: Here is the relevant Ninject code on the page.

```
public static class RegisterHubs
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        var resolver = new NinjectSignalRDependencyResolver(kernel);

        kernel.Bind<IStockTicker>()
            .To<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.StockTicker.StockTicker>()
            .InSingletonScope();

        kernel.Bind<IHubConnectionContext>().ToMethod(context =>
                resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().
                    GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>().Clients
            ).WhenInjectedInto<IStockTicker>();

        var config = new HubConfiguration()
        {
            Resolver = resolver
        };

        App.MapSignalR(config);
    }
}
```

**Update 2**: Thought I would also add the objects trying to be composed.

```
public class StockTickerHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IStockTicker _stockTicker;

    public StockTickerHub(IStockTicker stockTicker) { }
}

public class StockTicker
{
    public StockTicker(IHubConnectionContext clients) { }
}
```

Comment: There are two `RegisterHubs.Start` in the article. Where do you get stuck? Please post your code.

Comment: Have you managed to get it working? Did you use `GlobalHost` in order to get the IConnectionManager?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Autofac does not have an equivalent of the `WhenInjectedInto` method. However, you could accomplish the same using named parameters.

Try something like this

```
using Autofac.Integration.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.StockTicker;

public static class RegisterHubs
{
    public static void Start() 
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<StockTicker>()
            .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed("StockTickerContext"))
            .As<IStockTicker>()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(c => GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>().Clients)
            .Named<IHubConnectionContext>("StockTickerContext");

        var container = builder.Build();

        var resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);

        var config = new HubConfiguration { Resolver = resolver };

        App.MapSignalR(config);
    }
}
```

Note: The `AutofacDependencyResolver` comes from [`Autofac.Integration.SignalR`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.SignalR).

**Update**: Ah, I missed a tiny detail from the linked page; the factory function for the `IHubConnectionContext` is using the *resolver* to get the `IConnectionManager`, and not the container itself (of course the container won't know about a `IConnectionManager`). I switched to use the default dependency resolver (`GlobalHost.DependencyResolver`) to get the `IConnectionManager` instead. That should work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I gave it a go, and thought it might do the trick.  However, it is not hitting the constructors on either class.  I will continue to try different things and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: And you are absolutely sure that SignalR has been mapped correctly and you're hitting the correct path? What happens when you hit the `/signalr/hubs` route?

Comment: Sorry probably should have mentioned that earlier.  Yes, I had this up and running without DI.  I just wanted to switch to DI as an exercise.  It might be way I am starting up? I had this in the signalr startup class.  I will see if moving to global.asax/app_start may help.

Comment: Here is the error message that I receive...
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : SignalR exception thrown by Task: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.IConnectionManager' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Comment: Thank you!  that was it. And the explanation was very helpful as well. I really appreciate the help. :)

Comment: How to call App.MapSignalR from a console application? How to get a reference to IAppBuilder not using the SignalR Startup class?

Comment: If you're self-hosting using a console app, you should look at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host